# candied mints storage and transporting long distance

Tags: storage, mint, food-transport

I'm making mints for my nephew's wedding (containing powdered sugar, butter, white syrup). The wedding is in August. I have to travel more than 1,000 miles to wedding. I have two questions:

1. If I make them ahead of time, how do I store them to keep them fresh?
2. How do I transport them in an automobile?

Answer (score 1):

Your main limiting factor is the butter, which can go rancid and it highly sensitive to warm temperatures.

You should freeze the mints for storage until you take your trip.  You don't want them absorbing moisture or off flavors, so you want to wrap them very well, using freezer grade storage bags.  I would suggest double bagging, small bags in larger ones.

Get a cooler large enough to take the mints on the car trip, packing it with dry ice (which you can buy) or commercial freezer packs (sometimes called blue ice, such as [this product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000DH4M3) on Amazon) to keep the butter at least cool for the duration of the car trip.

You may need to plan to find a purveyor of dry ice at one of the places you stop during the trip, or arrange to have your freezer packs rechilled along the way.

Comment: Thanks for your advise.  All is do-able,and I appreciate your time!....sj

Comment: You'll go thru some pounds of dry ice a day, so it might be worthwhile to check your stopover town(s) online to see where you can buy replacement dry ice pre-trip. Also, carbon dioxide gas will readily displace the oxygen from a closed space such as the interior of a car. For safety, leave a window or two cracked a bit.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Good point on having the open window, or keeping the cooler in the trunk.  We only want to keep the butter cool during the trip, so freezer packs may do the job well enough.

Comment: You could likely also manage with just normal ice, as long as you're careful to keep things from getting wet. They don't need to be actually frozen, a good ice chest does keep ice for a day or two (depending on how hot an August you have), and it'll be easier to restock than dry ice.